# How to I resolve iFrame not scrolling on IOS/iphone?

Tags: ios, css, reactjs, iframe, jsx

I'm using an iFrame to display a document. The document is several pages and needs to be scrollable on iphone. Currently it's static and unable to scroll. Here is my code:

```
   return (
      <div className="policyViewDocumentContainer">
        <AccountFlowHeader guid={guid} history={history} handleSignOut={this.handleSignOut} />
        <p className="policyViewInternalHeader">
         Card
        </p>
        <hr />
        <div className="policyViewDocumentInnerContainer">
          <object
            title="Policy Document"
            data={`https://agency.${env}api.endpoint.com/agency/policyNumber/${contractNum}`}
            type="application/pdf"
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              minHeight: 'calc(100vh - 130px',
            }}
          >
            <embed
              src={`https://agency.${env}api.endpoint.com/buckle/policyNumber/${contractNum}`}
              type="application/pdf"
            />
          </object>
          <div />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is obviously only the render method. I imagine I need to adjust styling for webkit or something along those lines. Of course this is happening in Safari on iphone.

Comment: Where is the iFrame tag being used? I only see an object and embed tag here.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell exactly what's wrong from your code, but iframes not scrolling on iOS is a common issue. Normally, this is resolved by applying `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` on the wrapping element, like this:

```
.scroll-wrapper {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroll-wrapper iframe {
    /* ... */
}
```

This example + additional info can be found here: https://davidwalsh.name/scroll-iframes-ios